# Sonar Qube - Unexpected exit code received from batch file : 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sonarqube, tfs-2015, sonarqube-scan

I am using VS2013. My code is in git. I have push that code in TFS server 2015 and ran the build.Build failed with `Unexpected exit code received from batch file : 1` with some issues. Please help.

```
> Error                                                     
  -09T12:55:49.7287222Z INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=141ms

2017-06-09T12:55:49.7287222Z INFO: Load active rules

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z INFO: Total time: 6.016s

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z INFO: Final Memory: 42M/101M

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z ##[error]ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z ##[error]java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.3849589Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4005855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4162159Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.ActiveRules

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4318395Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4474834Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]... 37 more

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.readPage(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:99)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.load(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:59)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:102)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:63)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.provide(ActiveRulesProvider.java:49)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4630855Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]... 51 more

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]ERROR:

2017-06-09T12:55:50.4787165Z ##[error]ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

2017-06-09T12:55:50.6037153Z ##[error]The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully

2017-06-09T12:55:50.6037153Z 18:25:50.463  Creating a summary markdown file...

2017-06-09T12:55:50.6037153Z ##[error]Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

2017-06-09T12:55:50.6193618Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1

2017-06-09T12:55:50.6505888Z The build was not set to fail if the associated quality gate fails.
```

---

---

- Now it is giving following error- *                                                                                                                C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets (513, 5)
  The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
  System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.OnCreateCustomSchemaData(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.String>)' to access method 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components.Diagnostics.SqlTracer.ShouldTrace(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType)' failed.
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.OnCreateCustomSchemaData(String filePath, Dictionary`2 referenceMetadata)
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlTaskHost.CreateCustomSchemaData(String filePath, Dictionary`2 referenceMetadata)
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.ProcessReferences(TaskLoggingHelper providedLogger, SqlTaskHost host, ErrorManager errors)
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.LoadImpl(ITaskHost providedHost, TaskLoggingHelper providedLogger)
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.TaskHostLoader.Load(ITaskHost providedHost, TaskLoggingHelper providedLogger)
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteLoadTaskHostStep()
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteStep(Func`1 step)
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()
  Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

Comment: [Quick google search for that exact error](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/963) suggests `that warning was making it look like a failure - I removed the MaxPermSize (in my case was in a SONAR_OPTS env var) this results in clean log and no error reported by the task`

Comment: Where could i get MaxPermSize settings?Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

First double check if you have correctly configure the sonarqube related task in TFS build definition.

Suggest you enable more verbose logging to enable full debug logging for trouble shooting. To do this please follow:

> - Enable TFS Build debug logging by adding a variable named  **system.debug** and setting its value to 'true'
> - Enable the SonarQube components verbose logging - In your SonarQube    Begin task, under Advanced > Additional Settings, please add:
>     `/d:sonar.verbose=true`

The error message is similar to this issue [SONARMSBRU-202](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-202), the workaround is not setting *MaxPermSize*. If you are using TFS2015 update3 and above, you could also try to use the newly task: [Analyzing with SonarQube Extension for VSTS/TFS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS)

Comment: I added system.debug to true but still not working.Could this be Permissions error?Thnx.

Comment: @KB1788  There is a SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS environment variable, such as `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`. Such as the last paragraph in this link: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner.  To narrow down if it's a permission issue you could try to manually run the `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe` command by using your build service account on the build agent/server.